# Unable to switch from PHP5 to PHP7 using Apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache

I recently downloaded the latest version of AppServ (`Appserv8`) for Windows.
It installs `Apache 2.4`, `MySQL 5.7` and both version of `PHP5` and `PHP7`. After installing, the used version of PHP is 5.

I've tried to switch the version using the script "*PHP Version Switch*" provided with the installation but it seems not working.

I've tried to manually edit the `http.conf` file in `Apache24` folder but without results.

With these lines Apache starts normally with PHP5:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/AppServ/php5/php5apache2_4.dll
PHPIniDir "C:/AppServ/php5/"
```

If I edit with:

```
LoadModule php7_module C:/AppServ/php7/php7apache2_4.dll
PHPIniDir "C:/AppServ/php7/"
```

When I try to start Apache, I obtain the following error:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 180 of C:/Appserv/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Appserv/php7/php7apache2_4.dll into server: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.
```

(Part of the error is in italian: unable to find the specified module)

Note that the dll is in the folder as specified in the path. I'm stuck with this error and I don't know where I have to modify configuration file (if is this the problem).

**EDIT1:**
Somewhere I've found [this discussion](https://jaredmeredith.wordpress.com/2015/12/21/stuck-on-cannot-load-php7apache2_4-dll-into-server-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-try-this/) in which the author explain that, because of a dependencies of Visual C++, the DLL can be not readable. I checked my system, I cleaned it from multiple installation of Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable and I tried to install x64 or x86 versions.

With the x86 version, I have the previous problem.
With the x64 version, I can't start Apache because of a missing dll: it should be because apache is x86 version (I'm not sure of this).

**EDIT2:**
As suggested from @chugadie, I tried to use [dependencywalker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to trace dependencies.
I found several missing files with prefix `API-MS-WIN-CRT`.
Now I'm trying to fix but I have several problems with dll which are x86 and x64. I think the best way is to reinstall all components in x64 architecture.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I think you should look closer. The file must not exists. Beware of the php7 directory and php7 prefix of the dll

Comment: File exists and is in the right folder. I checked it several times before ask.

Comment: It could be that the php7apache2_4.dll has dependencies which are not met on your system.  Use http://dependencywalker.com/ to trace its dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

On AppServ folder on Start Menu (or Win Key + S) you must sear for PHP Version Switch and it will request admin privileges (if you deny it, it won't work), then it will show a cmd console rquesting you the PHP version to set on Apache, press 7 to switch PHP 7 or press 5 to switch PHP5.

If you did this and it won't work you should undo changes you did it on AppServ files.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with happy end. My solution:

1. Install https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=40784
2. When you install appserv you will see the "Visual C ++ Redistributable" window then push "uninstall" button.
3. You Install appserv and finish.

Arrivederci e buona fortuna.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try as soon as possible